# Setting WPF style on Window

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I wrote an XAML code in wpf, i defined a style in window.resourse like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
     xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
     xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     Height="400 " Width="450"  >

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Hello my friens!"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
</Grid>
```

in here, Test is my window class name. when i run that everything is ok but when i changed above to this

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="Hello my friends!"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

in design window, title showed as **Value="Hello my friends!"** but when i run the application, title become empty.
what this happens?
what is different btw **TargetType="{x:Type Window}"** and **TargetType="{x:Type local:Test}"** ?

*did not every of them refer to window type ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just specifying the targettype in a style, the style automatically applies to all objects of the type you defined it for. However, that does not work for base classes.

In your example, `TargetType="{x:Type Window}"` will automatically apply the title "Hello my friends!" to all windows. However, the type of your window is not `Window`, but `WpfApp1.Test`. Window is just the base class that is used. Thats why the style doesn't apply to the window automatically.

If you use `TargetType="{x:Type local:Test}"` instead, it will apply automatically to all objects that have the type `WpfApp1.Test`, which is true for your window. The automatic applying of styles only works for the specific type, not the base class.

You can also specify a key attribute, and then tell your window that it should use this style. In this case, you can also use `x:Type Window`, because then the style is being applied explicitly.
e.g.:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
     xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
     xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     Height="400 " Width="450" Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}" x:Key="MyStyle">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="Hello my friends!"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, such a descriptive answer, what i need :))))